# Why does random.nextInt() create "IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -1"?

Tags: java, android, random

I'm trying to create a quote generator app and a crucial part of the app is random(). But for some reason while the random is in my MainActivity the app won't compile.

```
package com.example.alpak.liftquote;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        // WHERE MY CODE STARTS

        //RANDOM GENERATOR that DOESN'T WORK

        Random rand = new Random();

        final int irandomIndex = rand.nextInt((3 - 1) + 1)+1;
        final int drandomIndex = rand.nextInt((4 - 6) + 1)+4;
        final int prandomIndex = rand.nextInt((7 - 9) + 1)+7;

        final String iIndex = "s"+irandomIndex;
        final String dIndex = "s"+drandomIndex;
        final String pIndex = "s"+prandomIndex;

        final String RiIndex = getString(getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(iIndex, "string", getPackageName()));
        final String RdIndex = getString(getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(dIndex, "string", getPackageName()));
        final String RpIndex = getString(getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(pIndex, "string", getPackageName()));


        //STRING

        final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //BUTTONS
        //

        Button inspireBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.iButton);
        Button deepBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dButton);
        Button positiveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pButton);

        // ON CLICK LISTENRS


        inspireBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                txt.setText(RiIndex);
                                                //"cannot resolve symbol 'index';"
            }
        });
```

The error message that I get back is:

.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -1

Comment: Paste the full stack trace, please

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? giving negative values to nextInt throws an exception...

Comment: @Sanruza What range of numbers do you intend to generate when you use `rand.nextInt((3 - 1) + 1)+1;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bound must be positive

Check the `Random#nextInt` Javadoc

> Throws:IllegalArgumentException - if bound is not positive

The two following lines are going to throw an exception.

```
final int drandomIndex = rand.nextInt((4 - 6) + 1)+4;
final int prandomIndex = rand.nextInt((7 - 9) + 1)+7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code cause a negative int

```
    final int drandomIndex = rand.nextInt((4 - 6) + 1)+4;
    final int prandomIndex = rand.nextInt((7 - 9) + 1)+7;
```

4-6 and 7-9 give negative maximum values

Answer (score 0):

When using Random, the argument must be positive, else it will throw an exception:

> Throws:IllegalArgumentException
>
> - if bound is not positive

Your code is generating a negative value in `nextInt()`:

```
final int irandomIndex = rand.nextInt((3 - 1) + 1) +1;
final int drandomIndex = rand.nextInt((4 - 6) + 1) +4;
final int prandomIndex = rand.nextInt((7 - 9) + 1) +7;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
final int irandomIndex = rand.nextInt(-1) +1;  //negative value in nextInt()
final int drandomIndex = rand.nextInt(-1) +4;  //negative value in nextInt()
final int prandomIndex = rand.nextInt(-1) +7;  //negative value in nextInt()
```

---

Note that rand.nextInt() will be evaluated first before adding the number after it. Hence `rand.nextInt(-1) +4;` ***is not equal*** to `rand.nextInt(3);`

Answer (score 0):

[`nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) produces a number from 0 (inclusive) to n (exclusive). For instance, `nextInt(3)` might produce 0, 1 or 2. So, values <= 0 just don't make sense; you can't produce a number R such that 0 <= R < n if n is negative.

From your code, it looks like you're trying to produce a random number between two values. Instead of `rand.nextInt((7 - 9) + 1)+7`, you should do `rand.nextInt(9 - 7) + 7`. That will make it be like `nextInt(2) + 7`, which is (0 or 1) + 7, which is 7 or 8. If you also want to produce the value 9, then you have to add one inside the parentheses. But in that case, it's probably better to just pass in 10 (so, `nextInt(10 - 7) + 7`), so that you get used to the idea of lower bounds being inclusive and upper bounds being exclusive -- it's a very common pattern in Java.

More generally, to produce a random int between `min` (inclusive) and `max` (exclusive), the formula is `nextInt(max - min) + min`.